# Vulkan render to texture

Tags: vulkan, render-to-texture

In an existing renderer which draws geometry in the swapchain, I need to render some parts of this geometry in a texture, others parts must remain on screen. All the geometry is recorded into one command buffer. I won't need to render this texture every time.
I created destination image, image view and framebuffer, but I don't know what to do now.
I dont think I need a specific pipeline, nor a new specific descriptor set, as everything is correctly rendered on screen.
Do I need another render pass, or a subpass, or anything else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exactly, you need a separate renderpass that fills your destination images. As the renderpass stores a reference to the images (as attachments) a separate one is required.

Within that renderpass you then can use subpass dependencies to transition the destination images to the proper layout. Your first transition should be `VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT` to `VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT` for writing to the destination image and once that's done you transition back from `VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT` to `VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT` so you can e.g. render your destination images in the visual pass. An alternative would be blitting them to the swap chain if the device supports that.

If you need a reference, you can check out [my offscreen rendering sample](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/examples/offscreen/offscreen.cpp).

Comment: Thx Sascha. I had already read your sample, but I didn't understand it enough. I see only one call to vkCreateRenderPass(), I was naively waiting another one. And I have difficulties to tell which part is for the main render pass, and which part is for the subpass. Therefore, how to make the subpass optionnal?

Comment: The main render pass is created in the Vulkan Sample base class.The sample does not make use of sub passes. It uses two separate render passes.